# MySQL Group By If Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have inherited a school attendance system using MySQL as db where an admin creates attendance records every week (planned) but during the week the records might be changed or deleted (actual).

I need to show all the different records between two tables(i.e.Actual v Planned).

Ideally I would have added a new column in "Actual" table and track all the deleted records but I am not allowed to change the schema.

I have created a MySQL [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92fee/5) that shows the schema and the query I am using to get the different records.

My problem is I don't understand how to merge two rows together and show the 
record that has value for the same day in same line. If I group by student then it only shows first record.

For example if a record exists for a student in "[tblPlanned]" but doesn't in "tblActual"  then I need to show it.  I also need to show the record that exist in [tblActual] but doesn't exists in [tblPlanned]

What I really want is somehow add a clause (precedence) that if the records for the student contains a value in either of the table for the day then show it otherwise show null.

Here is the SQL Fiddle [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92fee/5) showing the data structure and the output required

Any tips would be very helpful.

```
 SELECT * FROM (
             (SELECT a.Classroom as classroom, a.Student as student, 
      MAX(case (a.DropDate) when '20160222' then a.IsAbsent else ' ' end) as 'day_1',
      MAX(case (a.DropDate) when '20160223' then a.IsAbsent else ' '  end ) as 'day_2',
      MAX(case (a.DropDate) when '20160224' then a.IsAbsent else ' '  end ) as 'day_3'
FROM Attendance a
WHERE a.DropDate IN ('20160222','20160223','20160224') AND a.classroom = '17' AND  
      NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 
                  FROM Staging AS p 
                  WHERE p.Student = a.Student AND
                        p.IsAbsent = a.IsAbsent AND
                        p.DropDate = a.DropDate
                )
             )
           UNION 
            (SELECT t.Classroom as classroom, t.Student as student,
      MAX(case (t.DropDate) when '20160222' then t.IsAbsent else ' '  end ) as 'day_1',
      MAX(case (t.DropDate) when '20160223' then t.IsAbsent else ' '  end ) as 'day_2',
      MAX(case (t.DropDate) when '20160224' then t.IsAbsent else ' '  end ) as 'day_3'
 FROM Staging t
 WHERE t.DropDate IN ('20160222','20160223','20160224') AND t.classroom = '17'AND  
       NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                   FROM Attendance AS u
                   WHERE u.Student = t.Student AND 
                         u.IsAbsent = t.IsAbsent AND 
                         u.DropDate = t.DropDate
                 )
            )
    ) tbl  ORDER BY  classroom, student
```

Comment: Could you show us your original tables, here in the actual question?

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen my schema is available here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92fee/5

Comment: Can you better describe the exact output you're looking for, in terms of columns and conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were you looking for something like this? Either `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` the subqueries depending on which one you want to have precedence and then use the `IFNULL` function.

```
SELECT tbl2.classroom, tbl2.student, IFNULL(tbl2.day_1, tbl1.day_1) day_1
  ,IFNULL(tbl2.day_2, tbl1.day_2) day_2, IFNULL(tbl2.day_3, tbl1.day_3) day_3 
FROM 
((SELECT
  a.Classroom as classroom,
  a.Student as student,
  MAX( case (a.DropDate)
       when '20160222'
       then a.IsAbsent
       else ' '  end ) as 'day_1',
  MAX( case (a.DropDate)
       when '20160223'
       then a.IsAbsent
       else ' '  end ) as 'day_2',
  MAX( case (a.DropDate)
       when '20160224'
       then a.IsAbsent
       else ' '  end ) as 'day_3'
  FROM Attendance a
  WHERE a.DropDate IN ('20160222','20160223','20160224')
  AND a.classroom = '17'
  AND  NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM Staging AS p
        WHERE p.Student = a.Student
          AND p.IsAbsent = a.IsAbsent
          AND p.DropDate = a.DropDate
      )
) as tbl1
RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT
  t.Classroom as classroom,
  t.Student as student,
  MAX( case (t.DropDate)
       when '20160222'
       then t.IsAbsent
       else ' '  end ) as 'day_1',
  MAX( case (t.DropDate)
       when '20160223'
       then t.IsAbsent
       else ' '  end ) as 'day_2',
  MAX( case (t.DropDate)
       when '20160224'
       then t.IsAbsent
       else ' '  end ) as 'day_3'
FROM Staging t
WHERE t.DropDate IN ('20160222','20160223','20160224')
  AND t.classroom = '17'
  AND  NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM Attendance AS u
        WHERE u.Student = t.Student
          AND u.IsAbsent = t.IsAbsent
          AND u.DropDate = t.DropDate
      )
)tbl2 ON tbl1.classroom = tbl2.classroom and tbl1.student = tbl2.student) 


ORDER BY  classroom, student
```

Comment: Thank you, that is perfect !! Is there a way to identify which table it came from. For example  can I show if it was tbl1 or tbl2 in day_1 or day_2 columns? Thanks again

Comment: You could change it to a `FULL JOIN` and select all the fields: `SELECT ..., tbl1.day_1, tbl2.day_1, tbl1.day_2, tbl2.day_2, ...` Then you'd know which table was null and which wasn't.